# Expo: React Native throws JSON parse error only on phone

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a user registration screen. When I fill it out on my computer, the action completes without any hitches; however, as soon as I opened my app on the Expo app on my phone, I get this error when I submit the form, and no information is sent to my server:

`JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Missing"`

The rest of the error is as follows:

```
* [native code]:null in parse
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

Here's the method that's generating the error:

```
  saveData = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true, disabled: true }, () => {
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: 
        {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(
        {
          username: this.state.username,
          password: this.state.password,
          email: this.state.email
        })
      }).then((response => { return response.json(); })).then((responseJson) => {
        alert(responseJson);
        this.setState({ loading: false, disabled: false });
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        this.setState({ loading: false, disabled: false });
      })
    });
  }
```

I'm not really sure where to even start on figuring this one out, since it works perfectly fine out of my computer's browser. I don't have any other devices on hand to try this out on, either. This error shows up in my console, but it doesn't show up on the Metro Bundler window in my browser, and it doesn't show up on my phone, either. I'm running this off an iPhone 8 on iOS 13 and the latest version of Expo. Any ideas?

Comment: you're probably not getting the response that you expect. try logging `response.text()` (also a promise) and you will see it is not json, but probably a server error.

Comment: @brentvatne Got the log to spit this out: `Promise { "_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null, }` I'll be honest that I don't really know what this means, but nonetheless I can't really imagine this is a server error since I got it to work fine out of my computer browser. Is this log indicative of some other systematic error, though?

Comment: `response.text()` returns a promise. you have to use `response.text().then(text => console.log(text))` or use `async/await`